# Even ips pinging but odd ips not pinging

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, network, hsrp

We have following network, and i have multiple host connected to `TOR` switches configured with public IPs.

[image]

We have `HSRP` running on `vPC` switches.

```
interface Vlan100
  description *** Public VLAN ***
  no shutdown
  mtu 9216
  no autostate
  no ip redirects
  ip address 74.xx.xx.2/23
  no ip ospf passive-interface
  ip router ospf 100 area 0.0.0.0
  hsrp 1
    preempt
    priority 110
    ip 74.xx.xx.1
```

vPC config

```
vpc domain 1
  peer-switch
  role priority 10
  peer-keepalive destination 10.5.0.117 source 10.5.0.116
  peer-gateway
  auto-recovery
  ip arp synchronize
```

Interesting thing `host A` connected to TOR can ping every single public address (Example, 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2 etc..)

I have one more host connected on same TOR switch `host B` which is pinging google DNS (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 etc..) but not able to ping 1.1.1.1 also i have noticed its pinging even number but not able to ping odd see following example.

1.1.1.1  - not pinging
1.1.1.2  - pinging
1.1.1.3  - not pinging
1.1.1.4  - pinging
1.1.1.5  - not pingin

I have no firewall or anything, also we are adding machine on that TOR switch and noticed when we add new machine it has same issue but after couple hour that issue get resolved and machine start pinging every ip on internet

I have no idea what is going on.. need some debug advice from folks..

## UPDATE - 1

for experiment i did clear arp table on both `vPC` switches and my ping start working to all ips 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3..

`clear ip arp XX.XX.XX.XX`

I wonder why this is happening on all new servers? I do have `ip arp synchronize` setting in `vPC`  am i missing something else?

## UPDATE - 2

I am seeing issue like this https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/lan-switching-and-routing/nx-os-show-ip-arp-adjacencies-learnt-on-non-active-fhrp-router/td-p/2981353

If you see following result, on SW2 i am seeing `*` Flags in MAC address but on SW1 i am not seeing `*` Flags.. that is the issue, as soon as i `clear ip arp` that `*` disappeared and my host start pinging, what is that means?

```
SW2# show ip arp 74.xx.xx.166

Flags: * - Adjacencies learnt on non-active FHRP router
       + - Adjacencies synced via CFSoE
       # - Adjacencies Throttled for Glean
       CP - Added via L2RIB, Control plane Adjacencies       D - Static Adjacencies attached to down interface

IP ARP Table
Total number of entries: 1
Address         Age       MAC Address     Interface
74.xx.xx.166  00:17:53  3863.bb41.abc8  Vlan100          *





SW1# show ip arp 74.xx.xx.166

Flags: * - Adjacencies learnt on non-active FHRP router
       + - Adjacencies synced via CFSoE
       # - Adjacencies Throttled for Glean
       CP - Added via L2RIB, Control plane Adjacencies       D - Static Adjacencies attached to down interface

IP ARP Table
Total number of entries: 1
Address         Age       MAC Address     Interface
74.xx.xx.166  00:00:24  3863.bb41.abc8  Vlan100
```